# ¿Cómo evitar que la conexión sea rechazada?

Tags: linux, windows, configuración

Un saludo, quisiera que me ayudaran, ya que deseo conectarme a un sistema operativo **FreeBSD 10.3** instalado en una máquina virtual de VirtualBox desde mi equipo anfitrión que tiene Windows 7. Ésta conexión la estoy realizando desde la herramienta WinSCP y me dice que la conexión ha sido rechazada. ¿Tienen idea de qué archivo debo configurar para que las conexiones sean permitidas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega mas información acerca de qué has intentado y los resultados obtenidos.

Comment: Pues como ya lo mencione atraves de la herramienta WinSCP agregue las credenciales y la ip del usuario root FreeBSd del sistema al que quiero acceder para extraer unos ficheros y se me presenta este error **El servidor ha rechazado la conexión SFTP, pero escucha las conexiones FTP.** pienso que que hay alguna configuracion que este bloqueando las conexion, mi pregunta es que fichero es  @Mauricio

Comment: Intenta desabilitando tu cortafuegos y el antiviru si lo tienes..
Saludos!!!

Comment: Esto es una opcion que se debe de tener en cuenta primeramente ya que la firewall puede ocasionar ,pero en mi caso no es el firewall ya que lo tengo apagado muchas gracias @Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar habilitando la conexion ftpd en el archivo etc/defaults/rc.conf, cambiando el valor "NO" por "YES"